How to detect if an iframe fails to load due to X-Frame-Options or CSP frame-ancestors restrictions?
I'm trying to detect if an iframe fails to load because the target website has either:

Set X-Frame-Options to prevent embedding
Implemented Content Security Policy (CSP) with restrictive frame-ancestors directive

Here's my current code:
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://example.com"></iframe>

document.getElementById('myFrame').onload = function() {
    console.log('iframe loaded');
};

document.getElementById('myFrame').onerror = function() {
    console.log('iframe failed to load');
};

The iframe can fail to load in these scenarios:

When target site sets X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN or X-Frame-Options: DENY
When target site has CSP header like:
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
// or
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';



However, in both cases, the onerror event doesn't fire. I've tried these approaches:

Checking iframe.contentWindow
Using window.addEventListener('error',...)
Monitoring the iframe's readyState
Trying to access iframe.contentDocument (throws security error)

None of these methods reliably detect when the iframe fails to load due to either X-Frame-Options or CSP restrictions.
Is there a reliable way to detect these security-related loading failures? I need to show appropriate fallback content when embedding is prevented.
Expected behavior:

Detect when iframe content fails to load due to X-Frame-Options or CSP frame-ancestors
Show alternative content to users

Current behavior:

Silent failure
No error events triggered
Empty iframe displayed


I think the <iframe> element never fires an error event, no matter what. Even network errors lead to a load event. Maybe something would be observable by a ServiceWorker, but I doubt it very much. If you have control over the content that gets embedded though, you could postMessage to the embedder to let it know the page did load normally.

Unfortunately, I have no control over the embedded page

Getting any feedback from the iframe is impossible due to security restrictions in the browser.
An idea you might explore is using the Fetch API in the parent page to inspect the headers on the page you wish to load in the iframe, so you can predict if it will fail.

For fetch to be able to access these headers, a website would have to explicitly expose it in its Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header. I don't think there are many such websites with a strict X-frame-Options that'd do this.

@Kaiido good point, I guess you could get around that with a server-side script, that can return a true/false response to the browser.

You're right. I also suggested that the backend developers should handle the detection on the backend, but they didn't believe that frontend developers couldn't implement this functionality, which is why this question came up. Thank you for your answer.
